# Big photovoltaic current

Tags: solar-cell, photodiode

A photovoltaic cell is just a photodiode connected to a resistor.Now if

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6pJwZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I put many photodiodes in series , this would create a bigger current than in the first schematic right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1loXy.png)</sup>

If the photodiodes are parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu9mAE.png)</sup>

then we can create an equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkptu4.png)</sup>

and currents will cancel each other out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102228/discussion-on-question-by-mrs-chemistry-big-photovoltaic-current). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

The current of 4 cells will **not** **always** be higher then the current of 1 cell.
It does depend on the **U-I characteristic** of the PV-cells and the load.

F.e. if the 100 Ohm resistor is choosen to get the absolute **maximal current** of ONE PV-cell, 4 identical pieces in series will not be able to generate more current by definition.

Voltage sources put parallel with identical voltage (parallel, not anti-parallel) will **not cancel out** each other. I.e., the voltage is the same as with 1 voltage source, but no current will flow. The statement, that the current will be canceled out is **correct**. This case is fully symmetrical, no current can flow in either direction since the **symmetry would be broken**.

Answer (score 0):

> In my diagram don't they cancel each other out? Is the equivalent circuit wrong somehow? There is no external EMF besides those two photodiodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiPFy4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) has no load. If the voltages are balanced no current would flow. (b) has a load. Current will flow.*

- Photodiodes in series will give a higher **voltage** but the same current.
- In parallel they'll give higher current at the same voltage (as a single unit).